# constructor from another project

Tags: c#

I have two projects in solution - one is a library, the other is main program.
Constructor of one of the classes in library creates few other objects. Unfortunetly when i call that constructor in the main project that supposed to be made are invisible. Is there any way to fix that?

Example of what I'm talking about:

```cs
namespace Library
{                
      public class Foo
      {       
           public Bar bar;
           public Foo()
           {
               Bar bar = new Bar();    
           }
      }
 }



namespace Project1
{
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
              Foo foo = new Foo();
              //bar is not accessible here
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a project reference is missing.

Comment: How do you mean to use the `Bar`? It's living only inside constructor. It will be created in `Foo()` and as it is not assigned to any member of `Foo` it will dissapear.

Comment: I've added the reference.

Comment: Forget about another project. Can you use the `bar` in very same class? You cannot. it is a local variable.

Comment: Try replacing `Bar bar = new Bar();` with `bar = new Bar()` - the member is already declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign your `Bar` object to some member of `Foo`:

```
namespace Library
{
    public class Bar
    {
         // whatever inside
    }

    public class Foo
    {    
         public Bar BarMember { get; private set; }

         public Foo()
         {
             BarMember = new Bar();    
         }
    }
}



 namespace Project1
 {
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             Foo foo = new Foo();
             // foo.BarMember is accessible here
         }
     }
 }
```

**Basically:**

- New `Bar` object must be assigned to `Foo`'s member
- Class `Bar` needs to be declared in common scope of two projects - just declare it inside your `Library`. It also must be `public` - shared between projects.

Comment: Right. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You're simply hiding your `bar` instance field in `Foo`'s ctor, because you redeclare `bar` as a local variable (you should have a compiler warning about that).

Just do that:

```
namespace Library
{                
     public class Foo
     {       
          public Bar bar;
          public Foo()
          {
               this.bar = new Bar();    
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
```

This is declaring a new local variable named `bar` and assigning the newly created value to it.  This does not set the field `Foo.bar` because the local essentially shadows the field.  In order to set the field remove the declaration

```
bar = new Bar();
```

Or if you want to be explicit you can use `this`

```
this.bar = new Bar();
```

Either of this will set the field `Foo.bar` to the newly created value.  This will then be accessible to the creator of `Foo`